# docker ECONNREFUSED when connecting npm api to MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, npm

Hello I'm trying to get a simple nodeJS API application to work with data in an MySQL database using docker. But I'm running into an ECONNREFUSED error, and I think it's because of the way I'm setting up my containers / ports / ips thats stopping my API container from communicating to my MySQL container. I'll illustrate my workflow below:

```
//start docker network mysql-net
docker network create --driver bridge mysql-net
//Launch a docker container running a MySQL server in detached mode
docker run -d --name mysql-server --network mysql-net -p 3306:3306 -e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword" -e "MYSQL_DATABASE=bookaplace" -e "MYSQL_USER=bookaplace" -e "MYSQL_PASSWORD=hunter2" mysql:5
```

At this point I connect to the mysql-server via command line, and manually create a 'lodgings' table in the 'bookaplace' database. I add data to this table with an insert statement.

I'm inside the folder for my API web app, which includes my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:11
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
ENV PORT=8000
EXPOSE ${PORT}
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

I can run my app locally using 'npm start' and it starts up correctly.

```
//build image from dockerfile
docker build -t book-a-place-api .

//launch docker book-a-place-api container to port 8000
docker run -d --name book-a-place-api --network mysql-net -p 8000:8000 book-a-place-api
```

So now at this point I have my book-a-place-api container and mysql-server container both up and running. 
I'm trying to get just one endpoint working, a get request to /lodgings. I access this request with http://localhost:8000/lodgings , and can see in my book-a-place-api logs that the connection to the MySQL database failed:

[image]

I think it has something to do with how im connecting to my mysql-server container? In my book-a-place-api files I'm trying to connect to the mysql database with this code:

```
const mysqlHost = 'mysql-net'; 
const mysqlPort = 3306; 
const mysqlDBName = 'bookaplace';
const mysqlUser = 'root';
const mysqlPassword = 'rootpassword'; 

const mysqlPool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 1000,
  connectTimeout  : 60 * 60 * 1000,
  acquireTimeout  : 60 * 60 * 1000,
  timeout         : 60 * 60 * 1000,
  host: mysqlHost,
  port: mysqlPort,
  database: mysqlDBName,
  user: mysqlUser,
  password: mysqlPassword
});
```

Comment: `mysqlHost` should match the `--name` of the server container (`mysql-server`).  Better still, use `process.env.MYSQL_HOST` and configure this via an environment variable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The DNS name to connect to is the container name, `mysql-server`, not the network name `mysql-net`. Update your file with:

```
const mysqlHost = 'mysql-server'; 
const mysqlPort = 3306; 
const mysqlDBName = 'bookaplace';
const mysqlUser = 'root';
const mysqlPassword = 'rootpassword'; 

const mysqlPool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 1000,
  connectTimeout  : 60 * 60 * 1000,
  acquireTimeout  : 60 * 60 * 1000,
  timeout         : 60 * 60 * 1000,
  host: mysqlHost,
  port: mysqlPort,
  database: mysqlDBName,
  user: mysqlUser,
  password: mysqlPassword
});
```